# NPM list installed packages in readable report

Tags: npm

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to produce an easily readable report of all the packages installed in an project. This is to produce a report for security audit purposes, so the readout produced by npm list doesn't really cut it, as it includes the duplicates and the package tree.

Of course I could parse this manually or otherwise, but I'm hoping someone knows of an easier way.

This is on windows so no grep out of the box. :(

Comment: What exact facets of your project are you inspecting?  License, version, something else?  There are a some things that you can see, but it depends on what you're looking for.  Please provide more detail.

Comment: I'm really just looking for package name and version. The same output as npm list but without the tree and the duplicates.

Comment: Then what about `npm list --depth=0`?

Comment: I'd like to generate a recursive list and depth=0 leaves out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a completely perfect solution but is a step in the right direction:

```
npm la -parseable=true
```

The la command is similar to list but provides extended information, and parseable provides a single list instead of list view.

Full documentation at : https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls.html